# normal random variable distribution

Tags: statistics, probability-theory, normal-distribution

i have such problem in the book of Applied statistic and probability for Enigneering  and need some help to solve it.problem is following:

Let random variable X denote  a measurement  from a manufactured product,suppose target value for this measurement is  m,for example ,X could denoted dimensional length and target might be 10 millimeters,The quality loss of process producing the product is defined to be expected value of $(k(X-m)^2)$ $,where k is constant ,that relates a deviation from target to loss measured in dollars.
we have additional two  situation
1.suppose that X is a continuous random variable with

$E(X)=m$   and $V(x)=\sigma^2$
whit is quality loss of the process?

2.suppose that X is a continuous random variable with

$E(X)=u$   and $V(x)=\sigma^2$
whit is quality loss of the process?

here u  denotes usual mean  character(sorry i could not type exact form by Latex)
because as it seems that,this is a normal distribution,we have formula

[image]

which  express  probbaility density function of normal variable,no i did not understand how to use this formula for answer  questions,also i have doubt, that does expected value means mean value?i mean if there is given that expected value is equal to $(k(X-m)^2)$ ,does it means that,instead of mean,i should put $(k(X-m)^2)$ in the equation of probability density function of normal distribution?sorry if my question is too big,i could not describe it  shortly.please help me

Comment: Hint: $E[aX] = aE[X], E[k(X-m)^2] = kE[(X-m)^2]$.  Do you know the value of $E[(X-m)^2]$ for a normal random variable with mean $m$ and variance $\sigma^2$? How about for any other kind of random variable with mean $m$ and variance $\sigma^2$?

Comment: no in book there is not given it

Comment: `$E[X] = \mu $` will give you $E[X] = \mu $

Comment: Additional hint: First prove that $E[(X-m)^2] = E[(X-\mu)^2] + (m-\mu)^2$ by expanding the terms in square brackets on both sides and using the **linearity of expectation** which for your case means $E[X^2+aX+b] = E[X^2]+aE[X]+b$. Expand out $(m-\mu)^2$. Now combine terms on the right and see if you have the same answer as on the left. Then, **read** the definition of the **variance** of $X$. Can you tell what is the value of $E[(X-\mu)^2]$? Since you know $m$ and $\mu$, can you find the value of $E[(X-m)^2]$ in terms of $m$, $\mu$, and $\sigma^2$? The value of $E[k(X-m)^2]=kE[(X-m)^2]$?